# Keyboard not coming for edit text when a back operation is done

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my first page, I have an edittext for the purpose of searching. Below this edittext i have a set of values shown in a list. When I give a search key n press search button, searching is done and the result is shown in another page as a list of values. If I press device back button and come back to my 1st page, I am not able to type anything in this edittext for doing another search. What may be the reason for this? If anyone knows please reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it worked. I cleared focus of the edit text when we move to another page.

Comment: Mathew: I'm having the same problem can you help me out. I'm not able to get to your solution. Please help